# Knowing the coordinates when I click on an image

Tags: android

I have a big problem!

I have an image on the screen and I know the coordinates by clicking on the screen, but I don't know how know when I click on the image I'm doing on it.

Someone can help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean an image inside a view. You can set an onTouchListener to the view and get the x,y from the MotionEvent. [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mEvent) {

        switch (mEvent.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              downX = mEvent.getX();
              downY = mEvent.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             upX = mEvent.getX();
             upY = mEvent.getY();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```